# Different blocked URLs stats in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, web-crawlers

Just want to know I got different blocked URLs stats at Google Webmaster Tools.
I blocked entire site for revamp and latest builds implementation. Here are different stats

*Under Health tab > Blocked URls > 2,580*

*Under Health tab > Index Status>Advanced > 1,784*

What's the difference between above stats?

Answer (score 1):

In these two cases, blocked URLs refer to blocked URLs by your robots.txt file.

However, if you have different numbers can mean that Google takes time to update data. In a perfect case, these two numbers should be the same.